# How do I achieve this color effect in the compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes, color

I have been wanting to create an effect where the contrast between the warm and cool colors, or the green and violet is very visible. At first I thought I could increse the contrasts on the A or B chanles of the LAB color space, but when I asked this question I was told that this is not the right way to achieve this efect. link to old question: [how do I work with LAB color space in the compositor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44531/how-do-i-work-with-lab-color-space-in-the-compositor)
This should be somthing that can work for animations. (I.e no pixel by pixel color correction.)

These are some pictures of the effect I am trying to achieve:

Effect #1
https://istoleyourcereal.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/warm-and-cool-contrast/#jp-carousel-117

As you can see the warm and cool colors are very distinct.

Effect #2

https://www.flickr.com/photos/iucnweb/6146692092

It was mutch harder to find an image with this effect, but as you can see the reds are very contrasted with the greens.

Comment: If you are dealing with a 3D scene, you can do this with lighting. For existing images you can use masks and color correct each part of the picture with a different  hues and saturation

Comment: The masking thing can be time consuming when you're doing animations.

Comment: For fast masking in some situations you can use nodes from [Matte](https://www.blender.org/manual/compositing/types/matte/index.html) group; e.g. Luminance Key will give you adjustable mask set up by how is image lit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a hue correct node and using the saturation controls select the color range you want to affect:

[image]